# property not found on object

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a textToAnalyze class and a xyzviewcontroller. The code below is in my xyzviewcontroller. I get a error:" property "textToAnalyze" not found on object of type id". I can solve this problem in two ways. But I don't know the reasons why I get this error.

```
segue.destinationViewController.TextToAnalyze = self.body.textStorage; //which will get error
TextStatsViewController *tsvc=(TextStatsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController; // solution 1
tsvc.TextToAnalyze=self.body.textStorage;    
[segue.destinationViewController setTextToAnalyze:self.body.textStorage]; //solution 2
```

Comment: Is it a runtime error ?

Comment: No, it's not. It's a compiler warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you have this error is that `segue.destinationViewController` returns id type of object and there is no TextToAnalyze property on that object. The solution you provided is that you cast the view controller to your custom xyzviewcontroller.
You telling compiler that this object is (TextStatsViewController*) and compiler knows that this object contains this property.

Comment: `destinationViewController` is actually `id` not `UIViewController` (see [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIStoryboardSegue/destinationViewController)). But otherwise your answer is correct.

Comment: Note that you don't _have_ to cast. You could also call the getter/setter methods of the property without casting instead of using the dot syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As Greg notes, the issue is that `segue.destinationViewController`, which is of type `id`, doesn't have a property called `TextToAnalyze`.

Both of your solutions will resolve the error. Solution #1 is more stylistically correct because it will inform future readers of your code which class you're expecting here.

Note that both solutions will cause a runtime error if `segue.destinationViewController` isn't a `TextStatsViewController` (or some other class with a `TextToAnalyze` property).

To avoid this potential future error, you might want to check the class at runtime:

```
if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[TextStatsViewController class]]) {
    // segue.destinationViewController is guaranteed to be a TextStatsViewController
    TextStatsViewController *tsvc = (TextStatsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    tsvc.TextToAnalyze = self.body.textStorage;
} else {
    // It's some other class
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Though you answer is also very impressive, Greg's answer is earlier. Anyway thanks for your answer.